# Clearing the contents of a resource file (IFile)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In the workspace we have a set of resource files which contain contents in it.

Problem: When I select the project we can get the resource file and now we want to clear the contents of the file. So we tried to get the resource file as `IFile` and if we try to use the `IFile::delete()` method it is deleting the resource file from workspace instead of clearing the contents.

How can we clear the contents of the `IFile` present in the workspace without deleting the IFile form the workspace?

Comment: I see you're new to SO

If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IFile::setContents()` to change the contents of a file.

To clear the content of the file, use an empty input stream:

```java
InputStream newContents = new ByteArrayInputStream( new byte[ 0 ] );
IProgressmonitor monitor = ...
file.setContents( newContents, IResource.KEEP_HISTORY, monitor );
```

The `KEEP_HISTORY` flag keeps the previous contents in the history so that user could go back to earlier versions with *Replace With > Local History*. If that's not desired, use `IResource.NONE`.